# True auto-login in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, passwords, firefox-extensions, auto-login

Is there a way to set up true auto-login in Firefox?  What I want to happen, is, periodically (maybe on startup, or once after signing in to sync), Firefox (or an addon) will go to all the login pages that I have passwords for, and sign in to them proactively.  So (for example) when I go to Google for the first time after logging in to Firefox Sync, I'll already be signed in (to Google).

This isn't about staying signed in in Firefox as much as simply automating the login process, preferably using the builtin Password Manager (which in turn can have a master password of its own).

Comment: I use Firefox as my primary web browser at home, and don't have any problems staying logged into web pages (including Google).  On the other hand, if this is the same IT staff that has your Firefox unusually locked-down from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1167080/firefox-auto-update-for-school-administration), you are probably fighting an uphill battle.  Unless you can convince them to stop drinking the Chrome Kool-Aid long enough to ease their restrictions, your options are rather limited.

Comment: No, staying signed in is not the problem (although it is the same IT :)).  They have FF installed on their Macs, just not Windows.  Anyway, the problem is that we aren't assigned computers or anything, and they all get reset each semester.  So I'm signing in to a new copy of Firefox quite often. (since I *do* use Sync).  What I want, is something that would automate the logon process after signing in to Sync.  So I sign in to Sync on a new copy of Firefox, and I wouldn't have to also go through the process of signing in to all my favorite web pages.  As it stands, the first time I go to [...]

Comment: [...] a webpage after signing in to Firefox, I have to also sign in to that page, as Firefox does not yet have any autologin cookies from any pages.  Note that this would not work to keep people logged in for *all* sites, since they don't all support auto login (or more precisely, *staying* logged in, e.g. bank accounts, certain email clients, etc. - not always a bad thing either).  However, it would work for sites such as Google, GitHub, or Stack Exchange.

Comment: Another nice feature might be to auto-login when you go to a page like the sign in page for Stack Exchange.  E.g., you click the log in button, and it goes to the page, fills your data, and clicks the log in button.  Major time savings.

Comment: Perhaps someone else has a better suggestion, but to be honest what you desire sounds like it could be a major security vulnerability.  Have you considered utilizing something like [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/)?

Comment: I have considered that, but honestly, it seems like a little too much trouble for the amount of switching between new computers that I do :/.  However, I don't see why it would have to be a security vulnerability (at least not any more than Sync already is) if all it did was utilize the password manager for filling passwords.  The main *new* feature here is simply the automation of navigating to the site automatically.

Comment: Again, hopefully someone else has a better suggestion, but the only thing I have heard of that comes close to doing what you describe is LastPass.  The one-time initial setup is rather time consuming, but is it really *"too much trouble"* in comparison to what you describe that you need to do on every machine?