# Firefox auto-update for school administration

Tags: windows, macos, firefox, automatic-update, auto-updates

Is there a way to let an administrator (or root on mac) type a password once to set up auto updates for Firefox?  This would need to survive a reboot, as well as not require the browser to be running constantly either.

A command line solution would be probably even better.

The scenario is that the school administration doesn't install Firefox at all anymore mainly because of the fast update schedule.  If Firefox could silently update itself when it needed to, they might be more friendly towards the idea.  Internet access is not a problem whatsoever.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm already aware of the auto-update feature, and that isn't what I'm looking for (or if it is, it's broken). I've spent hours on Google, and haven't been able to find anything relevant whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

This is not to be done via an extra password. You can lock certain settings by configuration files, which only an administrator can change:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has an option to keep itself up to date. It installs a windows service that manages the auto updates.

From Firefox Menus
Select the “Menu” button in the upper-right corner, then choose “Options“.
Select “Advanced“.
Choose the “Update” tab.
Select one of the following options as desired: Automatically install updates. ...
Check or uncheck the “Use a background service to install updates” option as desired.

Comment: This works if you're an Admin, but what about if you're not? Is there an option to have an Admin sign in once, to authorize the future updates?

Comment: Yes! The background service manages it so it doesn't matter if a user is an admin or not.

Comment: Also, hit your IT department with a clue bat. The fact that a web browser, of all things, has a fast release cycle is a good thing as it means bugs and vulnerabilities get patched properly.

Comment: And if that's so, then do you have any idea why I (the student) get a message saying that Firefox needs to be updated, and it doesn't have the necessary permissions to update?

Comment: Also, they do have chrome, which also has a quick update cycle. The main difference from their standpoint is that chrome's webshare is over 50%, and Firefox has less than 20.

Comment: Anyone who thinks that Chrome's market share makes Google's browser the superior product probably hadn't done their homework.  Firefox has a lot more customization options, typically utilizes less RAM, and doesn't have the privacy issues that Chrome does.  Regardless, has your organization considered using [Firefox Extended Support Release (ESR)](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/)?

Comment: @Run5k No, I don't think they have.  I might bring that up.  Obviously, that isn't ideal from a user standpoint, but it might be nicer from theirs.

Comment: I think there is a much better chance that they would consider it.